# createWindow and inject stylesheet

Tags: javascript, tidesdk

I just recently downloaded TideSDK and I'm having some issues. Basically, I want to create a new window, using an external link (which works just fine) and then inject a style sheet to modify the window, like you can with a chrome extension.

```
var newWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        id: "newwindow",
        url: "http://www.example.com",
        title: "New Window",
        width: 1100,
        minWidth: 400,
        maxWidth: 1100,
        height: 730,
        minHeight: 500,
        maxHeight: 730,
        maximizable: true,
        minimizable: true,
        closeable: true,
        resizable: true,
        fullscreen: false,
        maximized: false,
        minimized: false,
        usingChrome: true,
        topMost: false,
        visible: true,
        transparentBackground: false,
        transparency: false
    });

newWindow.open();
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this. I've tried a few variations of:

```
var css = "<link type='text/css' href='app://style.css' />";

newWindow.document.getElementById('body').appendChild();
```

Nothing gets appended to the new window what-so-ever. In fact, no matter how I test the new window doesn't seem to be recognized as being there at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you control the source of the "new window"?

Comment: No, it's an external website that runs a service that I love, but hate the layout.

Comment: Unless you have the external site in an iframe on your own page (See [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-inject-custom-html-and-css-into-an-iframe/)), then it's simply not possible.

Comment: No problem. I added my solution as an answer.

Comment: After much research, it looks like due to the Same Origin policy that you can only do this on iFrames that are on the same domain as well :(

Comment: Fixed my answer to be accurate. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domains matched, you could add CSS to an external page in an `iframe` in your site. See [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-inject-custom-html-and-css-into-an-iframe/).
However, because the domains are separate, there is no communication between the iframe and the parent. Therefore, you have a simple, but unfortunate, answer: it's simply impossible.